# Strange answer from stringr function

Tags: r, stringr

I'm learning about regular expressions with the stringr package. An exercise for myself was to find the number of strings containing a certain substring. The right way to do this is

```
length(str_subset(words,'ing$'))
```

Along the way I incorrectly tried

```
length(str_view(words,'ing$'))
```

That second example gave the incorrect result 8. But in trying different things, that second command *always* gave the result of 8 regardless of what I was searching and which regex I was trying to match.

Why was I always getting the answer 8 in the second case? What is it finding the length of?

I tried several different sets of strings and always got the same answer. I figured out how to do it correctly, but was surprised the wrong way I tried always gave the same number 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str_view` isn't a string output, it's an object which has 8 fixed fields that help it draw the diagram e.g. `names(str_view(...))` gives you those objects

```
[1] "x"             "width"         "height"        "sizingPolicy" 
[5] "dependencies"  "elementId"     "preRenderHook" "jsHooks"
```

Can see in the `str_view(...)$x$html` value the ones where the string has matched:

```
str_view(letters[1:3], 'a')$x$html
<ul>
  <li><span class='match'>a</span></li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
</ul>
```

Hope that helps :)